# Check if function is fully executed

Tags: javascript, callback, extendscript

How can I check if a JavaScript function is fully executed without a callback function?

I am scripting for Adobe Illustrator and use the "save()" method to save my active Document. When it's done saving I want to do something, but only after its completely saved.

The method doesn't offer a callback function so I need another way to execute my own function, after the document is saved.

Comment: you can use the new "Promise" feature but it is not available in some old IE.

Answer (score 0):

Which SDK do you use? Probably *documentAfterSave* event is what you need instead?
(described as ***dco***umentAfterSave (yes, with typo) in [programmers-guide.pdf](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/illustrator/sdk/CC2015/programmers-guide.pdf))

Comment: the documentAfterSave Event is not supported in Illustrator yet